# When does the accepted answer NOT show at the top?

Tags: support

I Just ran across the following question which has 8 answers. The accepted answer received 7 upvotes. Two other answers received 23 and 14 votes respectively. Even when the option is set to display answers by votes, the two answers with more votes are displayed *above* the accepted answer!

Normally the accepted answer is always displayed at the top when the page is set to display based on *votes*.

Can anyone explain what is going on with this particular question that causes two other answers to be displayed above the accepted answer?

[Is it ok to breathe on the front glass element of a lens to fog it and clean it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30293/is-it-ok-to-breathe-on-the-front-glass-element-of-a-lens-to-fog-it-and-clean-it?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An accepted answer *written by the author of the question* does not float to the top. This is stated in the [Help Center](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). The rationale was to "prevent gaming", see [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).

Comment: Ahh. I didn't notice the answer was written by the same user as the question. Thanks!

Comment: In this case, though, it would perhaps be a good thing since the OP is apparently the only one among those commenting and answering who is aware that Nikon changed their public stance on the issue shortly after the question was created.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. People led to that question by Google may be wondering whether it's okay to breathe on their lenses for their own reasons, unrelated to Nikon. Over the long term, upvotes show what others find useful, which may not be in perfect alignment with what the OP was actually asking about.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the self-answered questions situation, there was discussion of this [on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264045/lets-move-some-negatively-scored-answers-from-the-top-spot) about a year ago where it was proposed to un-pin highly-downvoted but accepted answers. I don't think any changes were implemented, though.